# what is the common academic way of linking a section of a paper to a previously published paper?

Tags: publications, journals

Assume you have a published paper in journal X. Now, you are writing a manuscript for journal Y. One section of this manuscript is very similar to what you published in X. 
So how is the common academic way of referencing this section to that published paper?
I mean, it would probably look like this:

III. Method blah blah

This method has been previously addressed in this paper [ref].

Comment: Yes, you usually do it like you said. What's your question?

Comment: I mean is it common to reference the whole section to a paper? and leave it having only one or two sentences?

Comment: No, the paper needs to be self-contained. You can't just say *"Method: see [1]"* and be done with it. The sentence you mentioned is *in addition* to a suitable discussion of the method.

Comment: @xLeitix: I have severe doubts about the validity of the statement "the paper needs to be self-contained". While a brief description of the contents of a few key references may be given, it is usually very much expected that readers who are not familiar with a given method are not given a full description, but rather just a reference to another paper, where the description of the referenced method can be found.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The rule of thumb in my community is "if I need to know something specific about the author's earlier work to understand a paper, it's a reject." That includes methods that are not at least somewhat common in the community. You don't need to include every specific about your method, but the gist that you need to know to understand the principle *needs to be in the paper where you are using it*.

Comment: @xLeitix: Interesting. Things seem to vary considerably between fields in that case.

Answer (score 5):

The point of writing a scientific paper is to communicate what you have done and how. A key factor is to keep a clear trail of your sources. If you need to re-iterate an already published method you basically have two options:

1. Simply state that you use the method described in "so and so" (yyyy). If you have made any changes to the method originally described you do of course need to provide details on those changes.
2. If the method is somehow so key to your paper that you think it is worth re-iterating the method description then rewrite it in your own words and, perhaps, start out by saying. I have followed the method described in "so and so" (yyyy), what follows is a re-iteration of his/her/their description. You can of course include changes you have made to the method but then it has to be crystal clear to the reader what is from the older paper and what is new.

It is quite common, at least in some fields, to provide a abbreviated description, focussing on key aspects and ignoring parts that are more obvious. After all the reference to the original description should be given and the source for the information is there.

What you should totally avoid is to quote the section from the older paper. It is always better to provide your own version of whatever you are "quoting", since this may make clear your interpretation of what was originally said. Straight quotes hide such effects.